# Wrap my custom graph with boost::graph and calculate dijkstra_shortest_paths

Tags: c++, boost, graph, dijkstra, boost-graph

I've got a project with a large graph filled like this:

```
struct EdgeItem{
    int mPid1;
    int mPid2;
    double weight;
};
struct StationItem{
    int mPid;
    QString mName;
};
QMap<int, StationItem> StationsMap;
QList<EdgeItem> mEdgesList;
QVector<EdgeItem*> GetEdgesByPid(int Pid);
// and some other service methods
```

Stations map indexed by Pid. Graph's edges as MapLayerEdgeItem have weight. It's inmportant no not have to copy graph's data and use existing structures. I need to run and calculate dijkstra_shortest_paths on it. Please suggest what I need to start with.

Comment: See  the [Docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html) and [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp)

Comment: "When you ask Nix programmer for a toilet paper, he gives you an axe and shows nearest forest". An examples provided with boost docs graph is known as quite simple and not including all situations. You linked a sample that using simple arrays. I need to use QMap and QList without copying data to another format. Thank you.

Comment: You asked please suggest what I need to start. I think the the docs and example is a great place. If you want to use the built in algorithms you need to use the boost graph interface. Dijkstra isn't that hard to implement. if I were you I would roll my own. Otherwise you need to adapt your structures to the interface.

Comment: See this [adapting other graphs to boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/leda_conversion.html) and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418753/boost-graph-designing-without-adjacency-list-or-adjacency-matrix).

Answer (score 2):

In order do this you need to first adapt your graph to the boost graph library (BGL) interface. As mentioned in the comment look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418753/boost-graph-designing-without-adjacency-list-or-adjacency-matrix) which links boost's [how to convert existing graphs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/leda_conversion.html).

It seems you are really asking two questions. How do I adapt my graph representation to BGL? and How do I perform (and extract meaning from) Dijsktra in boost?

Both aren't exactly trivial if you are not used to BGL. Why not try to tackle the adapter then ask a more specific question when you run into trouble?

If all you need is Djikstra, I would suggest using your own implementation. If you think you will use other BGL functionality then an adapter is the way to go.